# jquery function not work

Tags: jquery, css

iam creating accordion menu with jquery + css3 everything going fine
expect that the menu always open when page load and the code to hide it not working
this is the fiddle i created

This is my jquery code

```
   $(document).ready(function() {

    //ACCORDION BUTTON ACTION (ON CLICK DO THE FOLLOWING)
    $('.zero_menu_title_collapse').click(function() {

        //REMOVE THE ON CLASS FROM ALL BUTTONS
        $('.zero_menu_title_collapse').removeClass('on');

        //NO MATTER WHAT WE CLOSE ALL OPEN SLIDES
        $('.zero_menu_content').slideUp('normal');

        //IF THE NEXT SLIDE WASN'T OPEN THEN OPEN IT
        if($(this).next().is(':hidden') == true) {

            //ADD THE ON CLASS TO THE BUTTON
            $(this).addClass('on');

            //OPEN THE SLIDE
            $(this).next().slideDown('normal');
         } 

     });


    /*** REMOVE IF MOUSEOVER IS NOT REQUIRED ***/

    //ADDS THE .OVER CLASS FROM THE STYLESHEET ON MOUSEOVER 
    $('.').mouseover(function() {
        $(this).addClass('over');

    //ON MOUSEOUT REMOVE THE OVER CLASS
    }).mouseout(function() {
        $(this).removeClass('over');                                        
    });

    /*** END REMOVE IF MOUSEOVER IS NOT REQUIRED ***/


    /********************************************************************************************************************
    CLOSES ALL S ON PAGE LOAD
    ********************************************************************************************************************/   
    $('.zero_menu_content').hide();

});
```

this is the full fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/YU6nZ/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add this CSS rule to make your accordion content hidden by default:

```
.zero_menu_content {
    display: none;
}
```

UPD. This version will also fix syntax error in your code:

http://jsfiddle.net/dfsq/YU6nZ/15/

I also removed `$('.zero_menu_content').hide();` which is not needed if you use CSS solution.

Comment: @dfsq you solved it with one error still remain in code...if you overcome that error then you do not need css heck.

Comment: Please respect the JS Syntax Error.

Comment: First of all, it's still a work around, because there still is JavaScript error in JS code. And what even more important - it would make menu unusable for users with JavaScript disabled.

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek 1). There are no JS errors anymore (404 image not found, because OP used non-working image src). 2). Of course it WILL NOT work if JS is disabled, so is it a problem of my answer?

Comment: @dfsq - I think he means that content will be invisible for any tool that supports CSS but not JavaScript (e.g., Opera Mini in my good old legacy phone). It's a usability gotcha.

Answer (score 2):

Find out how to open your browser's JavaScript console. Mine shows this error:

> Syntax error, unrecognized expression: .

... triggered by this code:

```
$('.').mouseover(function() {
  ^^^
```

Not sure of how that code should look but accordion works fine if you remove the complete block.

Answer (score 1):

You have one error too.

```
$('.').mouseover(function() {
    $(this).addClass('over');
}).mouseout(function() { $(this).removeClass('over'); });
```

You will get **undefined expression .** in console. So execution of code terminated there.

Answer (score 1):

You have following JavaScript error:

```
Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: .
```

When moving over:

```
$('.').mouseover(function() {
    $(this).addClass('over');

//ON MOUSEOUT REMOVE THE OVER CLASS
}).mouseout(function() {
    $(this).removeClass('over');                                        
});
```

Should be:

```
//ADDS THE .OVER CLASS FROM THE STYLESHEET ON MOUSEOVER 
$('.zero_menu_content_row').mouseover(function() {
    $(this).addClass('over');

//ON MOUSEOUT REMOVE THE OVER CLASS
}).mouseout(function() {
    $(this).removeClass('over');                                        
});
```

Correct fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/YU6nZ/12/

Answer (score 0):

```js
//ADDS THE .OVER CLASS FROM THE STYLESHEET ON MOUSEOVER 
$('.').mouseover(function() {
    $(this).addClass('over');

//ON MOUSEOUT REMOVE THE OVER CLASS
}).mouseout(function() {
    $(this).removeClass('over');                                        
});
```

This create a JS error so `$('.zero_menu_content').hide();` is not fired.
Take a look at the console.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
/********************************************************************************************************************
CLOSES ALL S ON PAGE LOAD
********************************************************************************************************************/   
$('.zero_menu_content').hide();

//ACCORDION BUTTON ACTION (ON CLICK DO THE FOLLOWING)
$('.zero_menu_title_collapse').click(function() {

    //REMOVE THE ON CLASS FROM ALL BUTTONS
    $('.zero_menu_title_collapse').removeClass('on');

    //NO MATTER WHAT WE CLOSE ALL OPEN SLIDES
    $('.zero_menu_content').slideUp('normal');

    //IF THE NEXT SLIDE WASN'T OPEN THEN OPEN IT
    if($(this).next().is(':hidden') == true) {

        //ADD THE ON CLASS TO THE BUTTON
        $(this).addClass('on');

        //OPEN THE SLIDE
        $(this).next().slideDown('normal');
     } 

 });


/*** REMOVE IF MOUSEOVER IS NOT REQUIRED ***/

//ADDS THE .OVER CLASS FROM THE STYLESHEET ON MOUSEOVER 
$('.').mouseover(function() {
    $(this).addClass('over');

//ON MOUSEOUT REMOVE THE OVER CLASS
}).mouseout(function() {
    $(this).removeClass('over');                                        
});

/*** END REMOVE IF MOUSEOVER IS NOT REQUIRED ***/




});
```

i have just put your hide() at the starting in,

```
$(document).ready(function(){

});
```